# Error is thrown when reassigning new Error variable in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, debugging, error-logging

I am using a package that is getting this error an I have figured out haw to reproduce it.

Basically assignment of a new Error() to a variable works, but then when you try to reassign it - it actually throws an error. Why does this happen?
Here is an example use case:

```
// Filename: test.js
var myError = new Error("Original Error.");

if (true) {
  myError = new Error("New Error!");
}
```

`$ node test.js` - executes no problem.

```
$ node
> .load test.js
```

^ This produces the error. However the package I am using does this similar pattern and gets the same error, but that is obviously not something I am doing in the node shell.

I have also found out that simply re-declaring the variable, instead of reassigning it will not invoke the error.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What is `if (true)`meant to be doing?

Comment: I executed  that and put the console.log at the end, nothing happened :
`
var myError = new Error("Original Error.");

if (true) {
  myError = new Error("New Error!");
}

console.log('Hi')
`